# If $f(z)$ analytic on $E(L)$, and $\lim_{z \to \infty}f(z)=A$, prove that $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{L}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}dz = A$ or $-f(z)+A$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $L$ be a closed, rectifiable simple curve, traversed
>   counterclockwise.  Let $f(z)$ be a differentiable function on a domain
>   $G$ where $L \cup E(L)$ ($E(L)$ is the *exterior* of $L$, $I(L)$ is
>   the *interior* of $L$) is contained in $G$. (That is, $f$ is
>   differentiable on a neighborhood of $L$ and outside of $L$, but not
>   necessarily inside.)
>
> Suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to \infty}f(z) = A$.
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{L}
> \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d \zeta = A$ if $z \in I(L)$ and that
>   $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{L} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d
> \zeta = -f(z)+A$ if $z \in E(L)$

Our professor gave us a hint: Pass to integration over a large circle $|z|=R$ (which, I assume must contain $L$?) using Cauchy Theorem for multiple contours. Then, use the following result:

> If $f(z)$ is continuous in the closed domain $|z| \geq R_{0}$, $0 \leq arg z \leq \alpha$ ($0 \leq \alpha \leq 2\pi$), and if the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to \infty}zf(z) = A$ exists, then $\displaystyle \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\displaystyle \Gamma_{R}} f(z) dz = iA\alpha$ where $\displaystyle \Gamma_{R}$ is the arc of the circle $|z| = R$ lying in the given domain.

The professor's hint is confusing me a bit, and I'm not sure how to apply it here. I.e., how do limits come into play here? Also, how do I use this circle to split the domain into multiple contours?

I tried applying it, and this is all I have so far: Let $\zeta = Re^{i \theta}$, then $d \zeta = i Re^{i \theta} d \theta$, so the integral becomes: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f(Re^{i \theta})}{Re^{i \theta} - z}d\theta $, and from that point, I am completely lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**  **Using the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and the [Residue at Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity)**

From the residue theorem we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{L}\frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'&=-2\pi i\begin{cases}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z')}{z'-z},z'=z\right)+\text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z')}{z'-z},z'=\infty\right)&,z\in E(L)\\\\
\text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z')}{z'-z},z'=\infty\right)&,z\in I(L)
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

> Note that the minus sign in the term $-2\pi i$ is a consequence of the orientation of $L$.  Although $L$ is traversed counter-clockwise, the contour $L$ encloses the point at $\infty$ with clockwise orientation.  And if $z\in I(L)$, then $L$ also encloses $z$ with clockwise orientation.
>
> ---

**Evaluating the Residues**

The residue at $z'=z$ is trivial to evaluate with $\text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z')}{z'-z},z'=z\right)=f(z)$.

The residue at infinity can be evaluated by transforming $z' =1/w$ and evaluating the residue at $w=0$.  Proceeding we find

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z')}{z'-z},z'=\infty\right)&=\text{Res}\left(-\frac{1}{w^2}\frac{f(1/w)}{1/w-z},w=0\right)\\\\
&=-A
\end{align}$$

---

**Result**

Putting it all together we find

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{L}\frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'=
\begin{cases}
A-f(z)&,z\in E(L)\\\\
A&,z\in I(L)
\end{cases}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**  **Using the Hint**

Note that for $z\in I(L)$, and $R$ sufficiently large we can deform the contour $L$ to a circle of radius $R$, centered at the origin, and enclosing $L$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{L}\frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'&=\oint_{|z'|=R}\frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}-z}\,(iRe^{i\phi})\,d\phi\\\\
&\to 2\pi i A\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

For $z\in E(L)$, if we deform the contour $L$ as in the previous development, we need to account for the introduction of the simple pole of $\frac{1}{z'-z}$ at $z'=z$.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{L}\frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'&=\oint_{|z'|=R}\frac{f(z')}{z'-z}\,dz'-2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{f(z')}{z'-z},z'=z\right)\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(Re^{i\phi})}{Re^{i\phi}-z}\,(iRe^{i\phi})\,d\phi-2\pi i f(z)\\\\
&\to 2\pi i (A-f(z))\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I'm not supposed to use residues. How can I justify separating out the singularity from the other part of the integral without using residues to get the same result? I suppose you could use Cauchy's Integral Formula, but how would you write that algebraically as an integral?

Comment: Well, without the residue theorem, just deform the contour around the pole.  The integration around the pole will result in the same answer as that obtained from the residue theorem.  Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: And thank you for the votes!!  Much appreciative.  - Mark

Comment: yes, I do need more help. I need you to show me algebraically what the integral looks like in this case.

Comment: as in what goes at the bottom of the integral sign. Is it $(|z|=R)-C$, where $C$ is the circle we can draw around the singularity?

Comment: did you forget about me?

Comment: The deformed contour is a circle $|z'|=R$, a small circle in the opposite direction at $z'=z$ plus two "infinitesimally adjacent" and oppositely directed lines adjoining them.  The integration over one of those lines precisely cancels the integration over the neighboring lines.